# How to display 2 google maps on 2 different pages?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have inherited a custom WordPress site that has a location page displaying a map and marker. I am trying to create a copy of that page with a different location.

My problem is that my 2nd map doesn't display at all, I know it's working because if I place the 2nd map on the first page both maps display correctly, only on a different page does the map fail to load, what is the issue?

Here is the code,

```
function initialize() {

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: cityliving,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        draggable: true
    }

    var mapOptions2 = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: bishopsgate,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        draggable: true
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas2'), mapOptions2);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map2);

    var image = '<?php bloginfo('
    template_directory ');?>/img/dot.png';

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: cityliving,
        title: "City Living London",
        icon: image
    });

    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: bishopsgate,
        title: "City Living London",
        icon: image
    });

    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<h1><img src="<?php bloginfo('
    template_directory ');?>/img/cityliving.svg" height="50px"></h1>' +
        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        '<p>21 Bowling Green Lane <br>London EC1R 0BD</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map2, marker2);
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
    marker2.setMap(map2);

    calculateDistances();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

//edit

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have different script causing a javascript error on the other page, otherwise you're not embedding your script correctly.

This code looks perfectly fine for me, your searching for a problem in a wrong place.

Try checking on both pages if console (chrome -> inspect element -> console) returns any errors.

Comment: OK I checked and there was an error on both which I am having a hard time understanding, I included a screenshot above, but the last line points to this "map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);"